# Can i use visual studio with Intel parallel studio 2018 and compile the app to Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio, parallel-processing, intel

Can i use `Visual Studio` with `Intel parallel studio 2018` and compile the app to `Linux`?

I want to compile my app in `Visual Studio` for `Linux` OS, but i want to use the `Intel compiler`, and all the `software` package `Intel parallel studio XE 2018`.

Comment: Have you tried doing that? How did you try doing that? In general, certain compilers allow cross-compilation, that is, generating code for a target different from host (CPU/OS). It will be easier to help you if you give any pointers on what is your idea of such an with ICC approach is.

Answer (score 0):

Searching the world wide web for terms "ICC cross compilation" seems to give this [answer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/538864):

> ICL itself cannot be used for cross-compile, but we have another product for embedded (Intel System Studio), which has the cross compiler provided for Android, WinRiver Linux, Yocto etc. We have official support for Android and WinRiver Linux because both them has windows toolchains/SDK. For other Linux (example, Yocto), if you have the toolchain for your target Linux, technically, you can also use the ICC (not ICL) in Intel System Studio on windows.

To learn more about Intel System Studio: http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-system-studio